# Is there a function for combining multiple rows with matching values into one row?

Tags: r

Hi i am having problem finding out solution for this particular situation below.
I have this kind of data set, a data set showing a public transportation data.
BSTN and ASTN are ID of public transportation stations.

```
#   card_id transaction  BSTN   ASTN  transfer  Ttime
#     1          1         a     b      0         1
#     1          1         b     c      1         2
#     2          3         e     f      0         3
#     2          3         g     h      1         4
#     2          3         i     j      2         5
#     3          1         k     l      0         1 
#     4          1         m     n      0         2
#     4          2         o     p      0         3
```

so I know that for card_id #1 a person traveled from **a** to **c** 
and I would like to combine these rows to make a data table something looking below.

```
#   card_id transaction  BSTN   ASTN  transfer  Ttime
#     1          1         a     c      1         3
#     2          3         e     j      2         12
#     3          1         k     l      0         1 
#     4          1         m     n      0         2
#     4          2         o     p      0         3
```

**The problem is** that for card_id # 2 the third and forth row of BSTN and ASTN does not match(f and g) which is a different situation from card_id #1, but regardless i would like to combine these rows if the values in "transaction" column
are the same.

would there be a proper code?

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that for each transaction, you want the BSTN with the lowest transfer number (0), and then the ASTN from the highest transfer number?

Comment: @Adam yes. for same transaction id s yes I have more data with different transaction id s though. I would like to subset datas with same transaction ids and combine them into one ro

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this gets what you need using `dplyr`. This might require more tweaking depending on the nuances with the rest of your data.

**data**

```r
df <- read.table(textConnection("card_id transaction  BSTN   ASTN  transfer  Ttime
1          1         a     b      0         1
1          1         b     c      1         2
2          3         e     f      0         3
2          3         g     h      1         4
2          3         i     j      2         5
3          1         k     l      0         1 
4          1         m     n      0         2
4          2         o     p      0         3"), header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

**solution**

Use `group_by` to define blocks over which you want to `summarize()` on. Then it is a matter of how you want to define the summary.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(card_id, transaction) %>% 
  summarize(BSTN = BSTN[which.min(transfer)],
            ASTN = ASTN[which.max(transfer)],
            transfer = max(transfer),
            Ttime = sum(Ttime))

#  A tibble: 5 x 6
#  Groups:   card_id [4]
#   card_id transaction BSTN  ASTN  transfer Ttime
#     <int>       <int> <chr> <chr>    <int> <int>
# 1       1           1 a     c            1     3
# 2       2           3 e     j            2    12
# 3       3           1 k     l            0     1
# 4       4           1 m     n            0     2
# 5       4           2 o     p            0     3
```

Comment: thanks!, but now im stuck with another problem some transaction ids  are duplicate for different card_ids  what if i want to do this process for card_ids that have the same transaction ids. Some transaction ids are same, even though they are different card_id datas...

Comment: Sorry Adam if you are  having a hard time understanding the problem. English is not my first language. I updated the question. The problem is that transaction ids could be duplicated even if they are different card ids. So I want to only combine datas that have the same transaction id s based on card ids(?) So card id 4 would not be combined because they have different transaction ids .

Comment: Yes, the `group_by(card_id, transaction)` will group on both. So it will only combine transactions within a given card. Having multiple "transaction = 1" records will not be a problem here. Did the code not return what you wanted?

Comment: now I understand your code! Thanks I think im getting what i wanted! Appreciate

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Sincerely appreciate

Comment: Sorry for being shameless but could I ask you one more question? I have edited my question. what code should I add to sum the Ttime of card_ids like the example I have edited

Comment: Just add it to the summarize line! `Ttime = sum(Ttime)`. I'll edit. I suggest looking through some of the help documentation on `dplyr`. I think it will help you out a lot.